# page-new.tpl.php shows page not found in browser title

Tags: theming

The page displays fine, however; the browser tile shows `Page Not Found | main title of site`.

How can I apply a proper title to this custom page when another page controls the header ?

Answer (score 1):

This will set the title in the actual browser window:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_set_title(t('Custom title'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I put the following in the custom page .tpl.php drupal_set_title('News & Info') is that ok or bad practice?

Comment: In general it is best practice to do that in your template.php file, substituting your theme's name for MYTHEME. But putting it in page.tpl.php has the same effect.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem.  First, I'm using zen and tried chain linking that code to the zen_preprocess_page in the template.php without success.  I can't just plop the code in cause then I'll be re-writing the zen_preprocess_page output.  Also, if I create something like page-artists.tpl.php, it will render(with the page not found).  But,  when I use CCK to add content, it overwrites the custom template and reverts back to using page.tpl.php.  Would you know what's going on here?  Thank you.

Comment: The drupal_set_title works fine directly in the custom page.tpl.  The cck content should only show up in the content region of whatever page you pass a node to custom or otherwise and.  When you go to /artist directly it should allways run the code on that discrete page regardless of what you pass it.

Comment: This solution works but I am still receiving the not found message in the recent log entries for any custom page i.e page--customname.tpl.php it seems that the source of the problem still exists.  Any idea what the source of the page not found could be?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your template.php

```
MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = t('custom title')
}
```

use the `t` function for translation

Comment: Thanks, Would this set it for all custom page.tpl.php or a specific one.  I have a few custom pages that I am manauly adding the title too.